# Can a bad battery damage voltage regulator?

Tags: battery, alternator, charging

I have a '91 Ford Sierra Saphire 2.0 OHC (pinto). Have been struggling with having no charge for weeks now. I've tried two different alternators, had one of them completely rebuilt by a professional, so alternator is not faulty.

Every time it comes down to the voltage regulator breaking. If I replace regulator, alternator charges for like another 5 miles, then voltage regulator dies again. (I've already repalced it 3-4 times, while trying, I pay 10$ for every possible solution :/ ).

I've double checked every single connection (alternator B+ -> battery, alternator D+ -> dash, engine -> chassis, battery negative -> chassis, etc.), I have solid Earth everywhere I need to have (at least according to my multi-meter).

Haven't had the chance to try another battery. Can a bad battery in any way cause serial voltage regulator faults? If not what else can?

Comment: Does the battery have enough capacity to start the car?

Comment: Initially yes(if I charge it with a charger), then obviously without the alternator charging it discharges, and eventually it won't start the car.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the battery from the car, charging the battery on a smart charger for 24 hours, then leaving it off of a charger for 24 hours, then check the voltage? Or at least bringing it to an auto parts store and let them test the battery with a tester?

Comment: Actually I haven't. My first thought was borrowing a known working one and try the thing with that. As far as I know a bad battery does not necessarily leak voltage, nevertheless I should've already tried it.

Comment: If the battery holds a charge, then for certain it doesn't have a short. If it doesn't have a short, then it is unlikely the electrical problems you are having are caused by the battery. Even if it does have a short, it is a near impossibility that it is causing the problems you are having.

Comment: Thank you for the input, if so, I'm probably pretty much stuck.

Comment: Although you have put a lot of time into it, electrical problems are always solvable, especially on older vehicles. I wouldn't give up. There is likely something in the system that you have missed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes, my regulator (which is indeed also a rectifier) was faulty along with other things. It turned out that I've had 2-3 issues present at once - that's why I've struggled weeks with it, but now the thing is working.

To answer my own question, it wasn't the battery and as others said it shouldn't be in a case like this.

Comment: How old is the battery ? Whats the battery's operating voltage 24/12 ? Whats the current voltage of battery before starting the car ? Do you have the circuit diagram of the regulator ?

Comment: What fixed the car?

Comment: I've described the situation under the answer below, I'm not sure what was wrong, but a complete rewiring solved it, so most likely a bad connection, but have no clue which one it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a theory perspective, I would say it is nearly impossible that a bad battery, all by itself, can cause an alternator to fail. The only condition I can even think of would be if the battery developed a short, but even for that to cause the alternator to fail, there would have to be some other problem in the system, such as a bypassed fuse or something of that nature.

Comment: You were correct, the battery is fine. I can't indentify the problem even at this point, when everything is working fine. I replaced a bunch of cables, sanded every connector and ground point, alternator was known to be working. The only advice I can give to people with similar problems is to tear the whole thing down, clean up everything possibly related and reassemble.